# How to solve performance issue of scaling images for responsive purposes?

Tags: html, css, image, performance

For some images I prefer to use scaling the image according to page size to make it responsive.

```
<img class="img_scale" src="img.png" alt"this img doesn't have width and height  
definition">
```

css:

```
.img_scale{width:100%; height:100%; margin:0 auto; height:auto !important;}
```

This solution works perfectly if the image is not a billboard background image or in a not flexible box.. So I would like to scale image in stead of using a jQuery plug-in.

However, It is often said that scaling images causes repainting and alot of performance issues.

What do you do? Is there a solution to overcome performance issues with scaling images?

Comment: Tangential question: why are you setting the height to be 450px, then overriding it with `auto !important`?

Comment: Just a mistyping:P edited..

Comment: Remove both your height properties - the first is being overridden by the second which is restoring the default value - extremely untidy. I'd also swap width: 100% for max-width: 100% which wouldn't force smaller images to scale larger than they are.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it depends on what "performance issues" you are really trying to solve. If you are worried about time spent re-sizing in the browser or re-flow issues, then use max-width: 100% on the image and set the image container's width preferably using a responsive framework such as [Foundations Framework](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or Bootstrap.

If you are worried about the time it takes to download images to a mobile device over a slow mobile network, then your image needs to be scaled or cropped before they hit the wire. Doing this on the client browser is too late. You can either do this on the fly or replace your img.src to one of several sized images based on breakpoints.

To scale or crop responsive images on the fly you could use a service such as [Pixtulate](http://www.pixtulate.com). They provide a JavaScript which will automatically detect your container's size, send those dimensions to the server and re-size the image server side in real time before the page finishes loading.